Resetear valor de select2 dentro de un formulario
Tengo un proyecto en Angular en el cual necesito que el valor seleccionado en un select2 se borre cuando se envía un formulario y que muestre el placeholder.
<select2 cSelect name="service_id" id="service_id" [data]="formattedClient" [placeholder]="'Seleccione un cliente'" resettable (update)="onClientChange($event)" #serviceSelect></select2>

He intentado referenciarlo mediante el id y tambien por # sin poder cambiar el valor directamente en el archivo ts.
@ViewChild('serviceSelect') serviceSelect!: ElementRef;

onClientChange(event: any){
   this.registerSaleForm.get('client_id')?.setValue(event.value.id);
}

resetForm(){
   this.registerForm.reset();
   this.registerSaleForm.get('service_id')?.reset();
   this.registerSaleForm.get('service_id')?.setValue(null);
   this.serviceSelect.nativeElement.value = null;
}

